# How do you draw the bottom half of a rounded rectangle on a canvas in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

I am drawing large rounded rectangles on a canvas using quadratic curves like this:

```
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ...
    ctx.moveTo(x, my);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, mx, y);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y, x + w, my);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y + h, mx, y + h);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, x, my);
```

I can draw a full rounded rectangle:
http://jsfiddle.net/s9x3xn4z/

I can draw the top half of a rounded rectangle:
http://jsfiddle.net/1oeduLqx/

But I cannot figure out how to draw the bottom half of a rounded rectangle.

My attempts all wind up looking like this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/tfyagcew/

Which is decidedly *not* what I am looking for!

How can I draw the bottom half of the rounded rectangle?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: did you consider using `rotate` to simply flip it? `ctx.translate(200,100); ctx.rotate(Math.PI);`. See http://jsfiddle.net/frankvanpuffelen/1oeduLqx/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the upside-down version of the top half:

```
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, my, mx, my);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, my, x + w, y);
```

The first coordinate pair is the control point, and the second is the destination. The midway point has to be `(mx, my)` and the final point is `(x + w, y)`.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple answer:

```
ctx.moveTo(x, my);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + h, mx, y + h);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w, y + h, x + w, my);
```